# using regex to iterate over files that matches a certain pattern in bash scripts

Tags: regex, bash

I have a regrex pattern `([0-9]*\.)+[0-9]*_to_([0-9]*\.)+[0-9]*`, a matching string would be 11.1.1.1_to_21.1.1.1. I want to discover all files under a directory with the above pattern.

However I am not able to get it correctly using the code below. I tried to escape ( and ) by adding \ before them, but that did not work.

```
dir=$SCRIPT_PATH/oaa_partition/upgrade/([0-9]*\.)+[0-9]*_to_([0-9]*\.)+[0-9]*.sql 
for FILE in $dir; do
   echo $FILE
done
```

I was only able to something like this

```
dir=$SCRIPT_PATH/oaa_partition/upgrade/[0-9]*_to_*.sql
for FILE in $dir; do
   echo $FILE
done
```

Need some help on how to use the full regrex pattern `([0-9]*\.)+[0-9]*_to_([0-9]*\.)+[0-9]*` here.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is simple enough for replacing it with a bash [extglob](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching)

```sh
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s extglob

glob='+(*([0-9]).)*([0-9])_to_+(*([0-9]).)*([0-9]).sql'

for file in "$SCRIPT_PATH"/oaa_partition/upgrade/$glob
do 
    printf '%q\n' "$file"
done
```

If the regex is too complex for translating it to extended globs then you can filter the files using a bash regex inside the `for` loop:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

regex='([0-9]*\.)+[0-9]*_to_([0-9]*\.)+[0-9]*\.sql'

for file in "$SCRIPT_PATH"/oaa_partition/upgrade/*_to_*.sql
do
    [[ $file =~ /$regex\.sql$ ]] || continue
    printf '%q\n' "$file"
done
```

BTW, as it is, your regex could match a lot of unwanted things, for example: `0._to_..sql`.

 If this is enough for differentiating the targeted files from the others then you can probably just use the basic glob
`[0-9]*_to_[0-9]*.sql`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use regular expression in `for` loop. It only supports glob patterns and that is not as robust as a regex.

You will have to use your regex in `gnu-find` command as:

```sh
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -regextype egrep -regex '.*/([0-9]*\.)+[0-9]*_to_([0-9]*\.)+[0-9]*\.sql'
```

To loop these entries:

```sh
while IFS= read -rd '' file; do
   echo "$file"
done < <(find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -regextype egrep -regex '.*/([0-9]*\.)+[0-9]*_to_([0-9]*\.)+[0-9]*\.sql')
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix the regex you would want to match at least 1 number before the dot, and if you go with it, a literal dot before the sql

```
([0-9]+\.)+[0-9]*_to_([0-9]+\.)+[0-9]*\.sql
```

https://regex101.com/r/5xB3Bt/1